# (SQL TERADATA) Having duplicate values in one column, achieve the output shown below

Tags: sql, teradata

Original Table

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-03-09 13:03:59.000 | 2019-03-09 13:33:12.000 |
| 2 | 2019-03-09 13:33:12.000 | 2019-03-09 13:33:19.000 |
| 2 | 2019-03-09 13:33:19.000 | 2019-08-09 01:07:21.000 |

Output (Getting the value of column 2 from the first duplicate row and the value of column 3 from the second duplicate row):

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-03-09 13:03:59.000 | 2019-03-09 13:33:12.000 |
| 2 | 2019-03-09 13:33:12.000 | 2019-08-09 01:07:21.000 |

Comment: For your specific example, `SELECT Column1, MIN(Column2), MAX(Column3) from MyTable GROUP BY Column1` would suffice. If you need other column values from the same row that holds the MIN and/or MAX, then you need a more complicated query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions like row_number() to identify the row that you want to be in your result set. For example if you want to pick the latest record based on column2 and column2, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Column1,
           column2,
           column3,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 
                                 ORDER BY column2 DESC, column3 DESC) AS RN
    FROM Table_Name) t
WHERE t.RN = 1
```